# Vagrant enters aborted state during apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I am running into troubles when performing an update through apt-get on a virtual machine bootstrapped using Vagrant.

In particular, I have a working configuration (vagrantfile, puppet manifest, and whatsoever). However I need now to add an `apt-get update`, and the following cases make the VM enter the "aborted" state:

1. Through puppet, an `exec` block running `apt-get update` as root, during provisioning.
2. Through poor man's provisioner, a `.sh` script containing`apt-get -y update` as alternative provisioner.
3. `sudo apt-get update` on the console of the VM when provisioned without problems (as said, existing configuration is working)

I suspect it is not related to puppet, as I remember it happened some other time when I was not using it. I hoped that, if it was a known bug, it would have been fixed by updating... especially since I am not using anything esoteric. However googling doesn't give anything! (Am I the only one using ubuntu on vagrant and wanting to update package list?)

The systems on which this happens are Archbang 3.19.3-3-ARCH i686 and (just to be sure it's not because I messed with Linux) Windows 8.1 pro 64bit - both are running Vagrant 1.7.2/Virtualbox 4.3.26 r98988

The boxes are respectively ubuntu/trusty32 and ubuntu/trusty64 and it happens with both version 20150427.0.0 and 20150609.0.9

Thank you for your help

(also side question, I am unsure if I should ask here, on serverfault, or superuser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant provision not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406602/vagrant-provision-not-working)

Comment: @Railslide thanks, but the problem is different - in ANY way I try the update, my machine aborts. In the question you mentioned, a guy tries the update in a non-interactive way and it hangs for waiting input

Comment: Do apt logs say anything useful? They should be located in `/var/log/apt/`

Comment: @JaysonMinard do you have the same issue if you do not provision the VM and just run `sudo apt-get update` from the console ?

Comment: Two things, make sure the VM is not running out of space, sometimes that crashes the VM. Next, open VirtualBox, select the VM corresponding to your Vagrant project and the Right click and choose `Show Log`. Copy and past complete logs on https://pastebin.com and share the link in the question

Comment: Those are old versions of vagrant and virtualbox...  I'd try updating them before digging in to this too much if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'sudo apt-get -y update' and it will auto confirm apt-get command.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. The problem happens in any case that I try update -even interactive- so it is not about the missing flag and about waiting for my input